# Which apps read/write an SQLite 3 database in Ubuntu?

Tags: sqlite

Have an app on another device which exports an SQLite v3 database. I wish to read and alter the content of that .db file. Tried Libre Office Base, no joy. Which apps will read that .db file, and edit it?  Hoping for a GUI app.

Comment: Editing an SQLite3 `.db` file requires knowing the SQL to make changes to the sqlite3 database anyways even with apps that can read the file - is there a reason you don't use the command line sqlite3 program to do that?

Comment: See added last sentence.

Comment: LibreOffice should work with Sqlite though... This will work on LO too: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_SQLite_With_OpenOffice.org

Comment: Libre Office did not as noted above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). From the site:

> DB Browser for SQLite is a high quality, visual, open source tool to create, design, and edit database files compatible with SQLite.
>
> It is for users and developers wanting to create databases, search, and edit data. It uses a familiar spreadsheet-like interface, and you don't need to learn complicated SQL commands.
>
> Controls and wizards are available for users to:
>
> - Create and compact database files
> - Create, define, modify and delete tables
> - Create, define and delete indexes
> - Browse, edit, add and delete records
> - Search records
> - Import and export records as text
> - Import and export tables from/to CSV files
> - Import and export databases from/to SQL dump files
> - Issue SQL queries and inspect the results
> - Examine a log of all SQL commands issued by the application

Install with `sudo apt install sqlitebrowser`

Comment: I'd like to add you call `DB Browser for SQLite` from the command line by typing `sqlitebrowser`. I think the command name is for historical reasons.

Answer (score 5):

There is an application in the repositories for Ubuntu versions before 18.04 called `sqliteman`.  It is listed in those repositories as "GUI tool for SQLite3 admin and developers alike".

I haven't used it much but it seems like it's a readily available GUI tool in the repositories.  If you are using a version of Ubuntu earlier than 18.04, you can install it with `apt-get install sqliteman`.

Comment: No longer available as of Bionic.

Comment: Confirmed at https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/database/

Comment: @K7AAY This answer could still have worked for non-18.04 users - remember 16.04 and 14.04 are still alive, so you need to keep that in mind.  I would have left the apt-get lines in there rather than just yank it out, while making a note this only works for versions earlier than 18.04.  (Remember also this answer was written almost 4 years ago, so you have to keep in mind the historical aspect of the answer too)

Comment: @K7AAY while at the same time making something that *was* an answer no longer an answer.  I've done some revisions to the original message that preserve the original content *but* add that this only works for earlier verisons before 18.04.  (If you edit an answer and remove the bits that make it a full standalone answer you make a historic answer no longer an answer - versus just editing the answer to indicate that the command only works for versions earlier than 18.04 which preserves the original answer but clarifies it doesn't work for newer Ubuntu versions)

Answer (score 4):

A method would be to use mozilla's firefox plugin called [sqlite manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/):

[image]

Comment: Support for this is dead as of Firefox quantum;

Comment: @neuronet So sad, before Quantum that was my go-to SQLite browser

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SQLite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl). Despite it is not available in Ubuntu packages repositories, it works perfectly well on this OS and is free and open-source.

[image: Screenshot of the SQLite Studio client]

The project is maintained since 2007 (as of 2018). It's multiplatform, [*feature rich*](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt) and can be extended by [plugins](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/Official_plugins).

Full history [is available](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/SQLiteStudio) if you feel like curious.

Comment: If it doesn't suit your needs, I strongly recommend DataGrip (commercial).

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Beekeeper Studio](https://beekeeperstudio.io). It's MIT licensed, works great with SQLite and can handle MySQL, PSQL, SQL Server as well.

My friend and I built it because we wanted a more modern feeling and easier to use SQL editor that worked for all database types.

I use it every day. Hope others like it too.

[image]